# Error: Source not found. The classes I have are build with the help of inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, instances

I am new to JAVA and this is my first attempt with inheritance. When I try to debug the below codes, I get the error: Source not found. I have no idea how to fix this. I created all of them under the same package.

If you guys need me to post more of my codes, please do let me know.

```
public class Agents {

  // The class has constructors and few variables

  }

public class User extends Agents {

  public User (){
    }

  public string name_user;

  public string assign_name_user(int j){
    name_user = "xr" + String.valueOf(j);
    }

 }

public class Comp extends Agents {
   public Comp (){
    }

  public string name_comp;

  public string assign_name_comp(int j){
    name_comp = "xr" + String.valueOf(j);
    }

 }
  }



  public class Comp_Behaviour extends Comp {

    // Variables and methods
    }

public class User_Behaviour extends User {

    // Variables and methods
    }

public class User_Solution extends User_Behaviour {

    // Variables and methods
    }

public class Process {
  public process (){}

  public static void main(String[] args){
    User_Solution solve = new User_Solution();
    int j = 1;
    solve.name_user = solve.assign_name_user( j); // ERROR: SOURCE NOT FOUND

    Comp_Behaviour behave = new Comp_Behaviour();
    behave.name_comp = behave.assign_name_comp(j);// ERROR: SOURCE NOT FOUND
    }
  }
```

Comment: @singhakash thanks for the link but no it is not a duplicate.

Comment: I tried your code and it worked for me?did you try the solution in the link

Comment: The solution in the link will not resolve my issue, I did look it up though. How come the codes worked for you, they are not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

This often happens when you don't have your CLASSPATH properly defined. Did you put the current directory ('.') in your CLASSPATH?

Comment: I didnt do anything manually. I believe I was very ignorant and naive in assuming that eclipse did everything. I will now google how to do what you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

when do you get this error while compiling or running the program ?
If compiling are you sure JDK is in use not just JRE ?

Comment: I dont know how to check for this. And, I get this error while running and debugging.

Comment: if you are running using Eclipse this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050504/java-eclipse-error-source-not-found

Comment: I checked it and you are right JRE is in use at window->preferences->java->installed jres ...but I am unable to change this, if possible, can you please tell me how to do it

Comment: You should download JDK from Oracle official site and configure JAVA_HOME/PATH variables and restart Eclipse .. Since you are new to Java it will good to  know that JRE packages libraries needed to run a java program . It is JDK which contains developer kit like compiler , visualvm , javadoc etc.

Comment: I already have JDK installed on my C drive in the programs folder. I have been trying to search the JAVA Home/Path Variables but no luck.

Comment: I am sorry for bugging you with this but I am really not able to configure the JAVA_Home path.                        I did control panel --- settings -- advanced setting---environment variable.. variable name(JAVA_Home) and Variable link:C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7                                                       But still I get the same error.

Comment: your JAVA_HOME should be C:\Program Files (x86)\Java not JRE and PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin